# Can i integrate DJI SDK in PHP language?

Tags: php, dji-sdk

I am working on DJI SDK and i have task of fetching flights(Drones) details using DJI SDK and displays into my web application. My web application is on PHP platform. I have searched that they have three SDK which are Onboard SDK, Guidance SDK and Mobile SDK (For Android and IOS) but don't found any SDK with PHP language. Can you please guide me, is it possible or not with PHP? Or do i find other approach to accomplish task.

Comment: @Dowvoter, Any specific reason to downvote? I need guidance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at the guides on [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), specifically [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @AesSedai101, Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To interact with DJI Drone you need a mobile device connect to the RC.
You will have to use the Mobile SDK at the minimum for your use case.
It could be an Android or iOS app.
With Mobile SDK you have access to all the "flights(Drones) details".

Once you have that going, if you want to "displays into my web application", then you have to sync your information from your mobile app to your server side. Using a rest API is one possible way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply